# Decryption Given final block not padded properly error

Tags: java, mysql, sql, encryption, padding

I am trying to decrypt a password from a MySQL Database which is stored in bytes as varbinary. When I place it throught the decryption  algorithm I get the given final block not padded properly error even though it worked when I tested it without the database. Im not sure where I went wrong.

Below is my code:

```
public boolean selectCheckUser(String username, String password) throws InvalidKeyException, BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, Exception{

    Key symKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm).generateKey();
    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(algorithm);
    String checkUsername = null;
    String checkPassword = null;
    byte[] cipherPassword = null;
    boolean check = false;
    try{
        stmt = (PreparedStatement) connect.prepareStatement("SELECT username, password FROM userdetails WHERE username = ?");
        stmt.setString(1,username);
        ResultSet data = stmt.executeQuery();

        if(data.next()){
            checkUsername = data.getString("username");
        }

        cipherPassword = data.getBytes("password");
        System.out.println(data.getBytes("password"));

        checkPassword = Encrypt.decryptPassword(cipherPassword, symKey, c);
```

and here is the decryption algorithm:

```
public static String decryptPassword(byte[] encryptionBytes, Key pkey, Cipher c) throws InvalidKeyException,
BadPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, Exception {


       c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pkey);
       byte[] decrypt = c.doFinal(encryptionBytes);
       String decrypted = new String(decrypt);
       return decrypted;



}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is here. You are generating a new key here. You need the use the same key that was used to encrypt the data. Depending on algorithm there might be a public and private key.

```
Key symKey = KeyGenerator.getInstance(algorithm).generateKey();
```

also

```
byte[] decrypt = c.doFinal(encryptionBytes);
```

doFinal can return one byte array but it can also need to run multipliable times to complete so what you need to do is loop through it.

```
byte[] decrypt = c.doFinal(encryptionBytes);
while(decrypt[decrypt.length] != 0) {
    decrypt = c.doFinal(encryptionBytes);
}
```

Comment: No its the same key throughout the program, or did u mean I shouldnt generate more than once? Also when I place the encrypted text directly into the decrytPassword method it works so idk

Comment: If you have the same key for both encryption and decryption. Then the it's most likly my second point that is the problem.

Comment: Ive tried it and it still doesnt work. Could it be the way I stored it in the database? Does that affect it in any way?

Comment: Well if you are not writing in the byte array correctly you can not decrypt it either.